# Why cone of revolution is not a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

I just begin to learn sub-manifold. I want to prove the cone of revolution
$$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2−z^2=0)\}$$ is not a submanifold.
Why we cannot find a submersion (like $f(x,y,z) =x^2+y^2−z^2$) to express the cone as an equation? I see there may be some problem on $0$ but I cannot express it explicitly and link it to some classical contrary example (like $[0,1]$ not homeomorphic to $(0,1)$).

Comment: What's your definition of a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Indeed your set is not even a topological manifold.

Comment: I guess a better argument Would be that if it where a submanifold it Would be locally homeomorphic to the disc but then removing the point that the origin maps to yields a path connected space which is homeomorphic to a path connected space, which then is a contradiction.

Comment: @Christoph I use the definition in the book of J.Lafontaine: A subset $M ⊂ R^n$ is a p-dimensional submanifold of $R^n$
if for all $x$ in $M$, there exists open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ and $0$ in $R^n$
respectively, and a diffeomorphism
$f : U → V$ such that $f(U ∩M) = V ∩ (R^p × {0})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me use $D$ for the cone (which is really a double cone hence the $D$), and consider the point $P = (0,0,0)$. Note that $D-\{P\}$ is disconnected, in fact it has two components $D^+ = \{(x,y,z) \in D \mid z > 0\}$ and $D^- = \{(x,y,z) \in D \mid z < 0\}$. For any neighborhood $U \subset D$ of $P$, there exist a point $Q_1 \in U \cap D^+$ and another point $Q_2 \in U \cap D^-$. But since $Q_1,Q_2$ are in different components of $D-\{P\}$ they must also be in different components of $U-\{P\}$. This proves that $U-\{P\}$ is disconnected, and this is true for *any* neighborhood $U$ of $P$.

However, in a 2-dimensional manifold, every point $P$ has a neighborhood $U$ homeomorphic to an open disc and hence $U-\{P\}$ is connected.